# Help with Mysql with 100K+ Table

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, performance-tuning

Hi im trying to develop a database design in which its gonna have 100K+ tables residing in it. 
My major concern here is will Mysql be able to hold that much amount of tables with no performance degrade.
Also mysql has a limit of open_file_limit of 64K but i know it can be overcome with ulimit, but again what would be the effect on performance when i have huge open files.
i dont want to have Error:24 in long run.
Also whats other parameter should i tune or have to keep in mind.
Did anyone try to have 100K+ tables in their environment with good performance???
My Server will be running Percona 5.6.14 x64 on RAID10 with BBU and 30GB RAM.

Regards
Rohan.

Comment: Why 100k tables? Smells like a broken design.

Comment: The answer is "You're doing it wrong". There is never ever ever going to be an occasion where a single database instance needs to hold 100k+ tables. You need to learn about "separation of concerns" and "single responsibility principle" and "normalization" and the like. This design is absolutely wrong for whatever purpose you think you're trying to accomplish. I don't care how perfect your business plan, or how epic your life saving device or scheme, 100k+ tables in one place is wrong. It's wrong. I know. I don't have to ask.

Comment: The answer is no you're not going to have 100k tables. That's one of the worst ideas I've ever heard. Just keeping track of it all would be nealy impossible. You either need to hit the books and learn about database design or hire someone who does know.

Comment: @jcolebrand, I just attended this talk a couple days ago: http://www.percona.com/live/london-2013/sessions/scaling-500000000-database-tables-and-beyond-wordpresscom-story

Comment: For the record @ShlomiNoach I'm quite certain they're doing it wrong as well. I don't excuse the fact that it works, or negate that experience. I'm just saying, they are doing it wrong.